# how to fix ImportError: cannot import name 'swapaxes' || can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, python-import

I installed tensorflow-gpu and since then my project import's went crazy.

eventually, after reinstalling most of my packages it comes down to this error which I can't fix:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\platform.py", line 116, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 289, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows\windows.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'swapaxes'
```

as additional information, here are my project's imports:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras import models
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sklearn

import freesound


from audioread import NoBackendError
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler

from tqdm import tqdm
import glob, os

from pathlib import Path
import csv
import warnings  #  record warnings from librosa
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle as pkl
```

I'll be glad for some help on this

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by starting a new project in Pycharm and copying all the files and folders to it.